# Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Ip Forbidden (CODE: 403)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have an App Service that has a private endpoint and virtual network configured.

I deploy to this App Service from Azure DevOps pipeline that uses a Virtual Machine Scale Set that is in the same virtual network as the App Service. I deploy to a production App Service slot.

However, I still get the following error:

```
2021-10-29T11:24:48.0057934Z Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
2021-10-29T11:24:48.0198779Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2021-10-29T11:24:48.0217137Z ##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App 
Service. Ip Forbidden (CODE: 403)
```

What could block the IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you [Christian Vorhemus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4610514/christian-vorhemus) posting your [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64845673/deploy-app-service-with-private-endpoint-via-azure-devops) as an answer to help other community members.

"The reason for this is because as you add a private endpoint to your web app, all Internet traffic to this app is cut off. Since the Azure DevOps Default build/release agents have a public IP, they can't access the web app anymore.

To resolve your issue, in Azure create a VM or a VM Scale Set either in the same VNet as your private endpoint of the web app. Then  [add this scale set as a new agent pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#create-the-scale-set-agent-pool). Finally make sure that in the release pipeline settings, the release is using this new agent pool."

Please refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477361/azure-app-service-deploy-returns-403-forbidden-with-ip-restriction) for more information .

Comment: i was facing the same issue but after icreated de scale set agent im receiving the follow error

##[error]Error: Error: Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://xx-xxx-xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=xx-xx-xxx'.

Any ideas?

thanks in advance.